# How to parameterize a fixture that's used as an argument to another fixture

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have the following tests directory structure

```
tests/
    resources/
        test_data1.json
        test_data2.json
        etc...
    test_module.py
```

In `test_module.py`, I currently have a different fixture for each of the test json files:

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_data1():
    with open('tests/resources/test_data1.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data

@pytest.fixture
def test_data2():
    # same exact implementation as above, just different path

@pytest.fixture
def test_data3()...

etc...
```

These fixtures are not used directly by tests, they are passed as arguments to other fixtures. The code above is extremely redundant; I'd ideally like a way to have a single fixture for the purpose of loading in the json data. Something like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def test_data(request):
    json_path = request.param.get('json_path')
    with open(json_path) as f:
         data = json.load(f)
    return data

@pytest.mark.parameterize('test_data', [{'json_path':'tests/resources/test_data1.json'}])
@pytest.fixture
def good_response(test_data):
    # process test_data in some way -- Ex. mimic the content of a Response obj
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with `params`:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob("tests/resources/*")


@pytest.fixture(params=files)
def test_data(request):
    with open(request.param) as f:
        return json.load(f)


@pytest.fixture
def good_response(test_data):
    # process test_data in some way -- Ex. mimic the content of a Response obj
    return response
```

Comment: Thanks @kosciej16. So in other words, there is no native way to do this with pytest, and I'm better off just using a plain old function to load the test data?

Comment: @OniBarolli It looks like my knowledge was a bit outdated, I explored a bit and found a way to do that natively.